# dynamic row inserts - MySQL PHP - how?

Tags: php

I have a misunderstanding regarding some dynamic row inserts in a MySQL table.

All I want to do is based on the EAV Model:

- I have a products table which contains products
- A attributes table which contains attributes (name) for products (group based - related to category)
- And a product_attribute which contains the value of the attribute

And the user must create this attributes to be associated with a product, and I'm thinking to insert `<input>` elements with jQuery's `append`.

But how to track inserts and how to append them to have a specific name : `<input name=''>`.

The result should do the following:

```
<form action='attribute_insert.php' method='post'>
<input name='field1' />
<input name='field2' />
<input name='field3' />
....
<input name='field20' />
</form>
```

and after processing in `attribute_insert.php` to insert like this :

```
('1', '12', 'manufacturer');
('2', '12', 'freq');
('3', '12', 'memory');
('4', '12', 'ram');
....
('20', '12', 'blablabla');
```

How can I do this ... using `foreach` to scan the `$_POST[]` or there is a clever method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not name them `field[]`, then you don't have to worry about the number. In PHP you can just do a `for` loop over `$_POST['field']`, since it will return an array of the fields ;)

Comment: I was just typing up the same thing :P +1 to you for thinking the same as me.

Comment: I don't get it ? how ? the `<input type='text' name='???'/>` is appended via jquery ...

Comment: Terw ? please explain ... if I have `<input name='field'/> and <input name='field'/>` the `$_POST[]` will interpret as an array ... like `$_POST[field][0] and $_POST[field][1]`? Thank you

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. But you have to use `<input name="field[]">` with the `[]`. Then the browser should send all of them and PHP will treat them as an array. You can also use `field[1]` if the number is important. If it's just random, don't include it ;)